# I'd like to retrieve the status updates from a user that Facebook has deemed "important" - is there a way?

Tags: facebook, status

As a user, I can subscribe to "only important" status updates from my friends.  As a programmer, is there a way for me to find out which are the "important" status updates from my friends?  I want to build an app that summarizes a friend's important status updates for the last year.  I know I can get a list of statuses, but I couldn't find a way to determine how important Facebook deems each status to be. If this can't be done, does anyone have any ideas about other ways I could "summarize" a user's activity over a period of time to only show  the significant stuff?
thanks,
Liz

Comment: Haven't seen this before. But if it should exists, it should be mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/).

Comment: I read through the stream doc you indicated, and while it seems quite comprehensive, it didn't offer any clue as to how to get "only important" status updates through the API.

Comment: Correct, if there's no `important` field to query either in the Graph or FQL table, then you're not going to be able to filter by it.  I've never heard of "only important"  can you point us to some documentation on it?